# Why is it acceptable for Meta questions to often receive literally dozens of comments but no answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, meta

Why is it acceptable for Meta questions to often receive literally dozens of comments but no answers? Couldn't a lot of the comments be converted into valid answers with appropriate comments following? I often scroll down for an answer and if there is none, I typically don't read the comments (but that's just me).

Comment: Because the Q&A format is unsuited for the large discussions that often occur on Meta.

Comment: Feel free to compile comments into an answer, if appropriate. Just don't forget to provide attribution.

Comment: Meta is a different beast. While discussion outside strict topical matters is very discouraged on main, it isn't on meta. Posting an answer on meta often only serves to condense and bundle conclusions of a prior comment discussion.

Comment: "Why is it acceptable for Meta questions to often receive literally dozens of comments..." Why should it not be acceptable?

Comment: Did I say it wasn't acceptable?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty You implied as much by the very nature of the quesiton.  If you felt it was entirely appropriate why would you ask the question in the first place?

Comment: Why do I have to make a case for why it's not acceptable to ask my question?  The implication of which is, that my very question is not acceptable.

Comment: I'm never asking another meta question ever

Comment: @GeorgeJempty You don't *have* to.  Someone asked why you felt that way, presumably to better understand your current understanding of the topic, perhaps to better determine what misconception(s) you may have.  It would help them narrow the scope of their answer to just what you need to know, rather than broadly discussing the whole topic, presumably also reiterating lots of information you already knew, or information you wouldn't need to know to get your answer.  While I wouldn't say the question is unanswerable as it sits, you answering that clarifying question would *improve* it.

Comment: Why is this question getting so many downvotes? So far I have not much experience on stackoverflow and for me it is therefore useful to understand how communication is supposed to be on this website.

Comment: @ArcoBast, [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Voting indicates agreement or disagreement, rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.

Comment: @Zanon: Ah, thanks. Because if I move my curser over the downvote button, I see the usual message " ... doesnt show research effort ... no helpful ..."

So i might start a meta question asking for that to change to "agree" vs. "disagree"?

Comment: @ArcoBast, your suggestion makes sense.

Comment: @ArcoBast I think that's been proposed (and shot down) a couple of times already.

Comment: weird ... if the function of the buttons is different, why giving the same explanation?

Answer (score 22):

Unlike the main site, **discussion** is encouraged on [Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> Meta Stack Overflow is the part of the site where users discuss the workings and policies of Stack Overflow

It is difficult to have a discussion in the Stack Exchange Q&A format without using comments.

> Couldn't a lot of the comments be converted into valid answers with appropriate comments following?

Yes, and this happens sometimes, but removing the comments would often result in the discussion being hard to follow. You can 'convert' your own comment into an answer, but you can't copy the comments below.

Answer (score 17):

Several reasons come to mind:

1. Lots of Meta questions are duplicates, and plenty of others are closed for other reasons. It is not generally considered appropriate to *answer* a question that you're voting to close, so users will not post an answer. However, they still want to make a comment, so they do so.
2. Meta questions tend to be more discussion-based than would ordinarily be allowed for Q&A on a Stack Exchange site, and the rigid Q&A format doesn't lend itself particularly well to discussions. Therefore, people who want to engage in a discussion have little choice but to leave comments.
3. The comments that are posted are *tangential* to the issue being discussed in the question. They would not be appropriate as a standalone answer, but they might still be important things to point out. The comments section is a perfectly reasonable place to do this.
4. Posting a real, first-class answer is *hard*. Or at least, it is a significant undertaking. [Lots of users have opinions that they want to contribute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality), but don't want to (or can't) take the time to write out a full answer. Therefore, they share their opinion as a comment. While we might ordinarily discourage this practice, it seems more acceptable on Meta because the issues are of import to all members of the Stack Overflow community, and we don't really need dozens of redundant answers anyway.
5. It can be tedious and exhausting to participate regularly here. Regular denizens of Meta like to blow off steam and bring a bit of light-heartedness to the exchange by leaving comments. Again, this kind of noise would be discouraged on other Stack Exchange sites, but is more acceptable given the informal nature of Meta.
6. In some cases, there may not *be* an actual answer to the question, which makes it impossible to compose one. Well, not actually impossible, since we also use a relaxed standard for what constitutes an answer on Meta (how would you otherwise "answer" a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), for example?), but either users don't know this or they don't feel comfortable leaving this kind of answer. As a workaround, they leave a comment instead.
7. Finally, yes: some of the comments can and arguably *should* be converted into answers. Sometimes the commenting is excessive and inappropriate. There is, however, no way to prevent this from happening. Occasionally, moderators will clean up the comments, and in other cases, someone will come along and post an answer that incorporates and crystallizes the discussion from the comment thread.

You don't *have* to read the comments; they are optional. If there is information that you *really* need to know, it will be in an answer.

Comment: Your first part is very important. For so many duplicates, its important that they be closed as a duplicate to centralize documentation on how the site works, but you still want to help the user out, especially if they're a new user.